# Multiple conditions on joining tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

If it possible to have INNER JOIN with a single table but with different conditions?
I like to know whether it is possible to combine the following queries into one:

```
UPDATE st
SET st.GLAccount = gt.GLAccount
FROM StockTransactions st
INNER JOIN GLTransactions gt ON gt.TransactionID = st.PurchaseTransactionID 
                                AND gt.Quantity IS NOT NULL AND st.Item = gt.Item
Go


UPDATE st
SET st.GLAccount = gt.GLAccount
FROM StockTransactions st
INNER JOIN GLTransactions gt ON gt.TransactionID = st.ID AND st.Item = gt.Item
                                AND (st.Type = 160 OR st.Type = 165)
GO              


UPDATE st
SET st.GLAccount = gt.GLAccount
FROM StockTransactions st
INNER JOIN GLTransactions gt ON gt.TransactionID = st.ID AND st.Item = gt.Item
                                AND gt.LineType = 1
GO
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, you can use `or` in the `join`.  However, this could return multiple results -- which should it use?

Comment: If I use OR wouldn't the performance suffer as its result?

Comment: The single query should be faster than the three -- as always though, try it out for yourself.  What I was referring to though was if your first statement updates account to one value, your second or third could change that value.  When updating values, it's best to be explicit with the intended result.

Comment: I think that should be fine since only one of these three sets of conditions will be valid at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE  st
SET     st.GLAccount = gt.GLAccount
FROM    StockTransactions st
        INNER JOIN GLTransactions gt ON ( gt.TransactionID = st.PurchaseTransactionID
                                          AND gt.Quantity IS NOT NULL
                                          AND st.Item = gt.Item
                                        )
                                        OR ( gt.TransactionID = st.ID
                                             AND st.Item = gt.Item
                                             AND ( ( st.Type = 160
                                                     OR st.Type = 165
                                                   )
                                                   OR gt.LineType = 1
                                                 )
                                           )
```

Comment: Thanks! May I know performance-wise is this one better OR having three queries executed?

Comment: You can test that yourself by using a BEGIN TRAN...ROLLBACK and looking at the execution plan.  It will depend on what indexes are in play.